# How to do this registration okta curl request in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, okta, okta-api

I am trying to register a new user in OKTA in Javascript with a curl mentioned [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#create-user-without-credentials)
. 
I want to make a curl format like this

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
-d '{
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "Isaac",
    "lastName": "Brock",
    "email": "isaac.brock@example.com",
    "login": "isaac.brock@example.com",
    "mobilePhone": "555-415-1337"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "password" : { "value": "tlpWENT2m" }
  }
}' "https://dev-662976.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users?activate=false"
```

This is part of code I write

```
  handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {};
      var profile = {};
      var credentials = {};
      profile['firstName'] = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
      profile['lastName'] = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
      profile['email'] = document.getElementById('email').value;
      profile["login"] = document.getElementById('email').value;
      profile['mobliePhone'] = "555-415-1337";
      data['profile'] = profile;
      credentials['password'] = {"value":document.getElementById('password').value};
      data["credentials"] = credentials;
      this.registrationApiCall(data);
      //console.log(data);
      //registrationApiCall(data);
  }

  registrationApiCall(data){
    return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://dev-662976.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users?activate=false',
            data: data,
            config: {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    "Authorization": "SSWS <my_ssws_token>"
                }
            }
        }).then(function(value) {
          console.log(value);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

I get a 403 error like this:

```
POST https://dev-662976.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users?activate=false 403 (Forbidden)
Register.js:72 Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

From the console of chrome, I can see two requests. They have same request url but the first is 200 and doesn't include any payload and the second include my `data` which is a 403 error.

I write this code referring this [dude](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/blob/master/client/src/actions/Registration.js) but I think his format is not correct, but it works well on his demo. Could you tell me how to make it correct?

I have no idea if I should use `axios`, if there is some better idea. Please tell me.

Comment: Maybe you Authorization token expired?

Comment: I've edited this question to remove your SSWS token, which should be kept confidential because it can be used to read all data in your Okta org.  Please login to your admin console and delete the token that was used in this post.